# how to stop executing a query or process in firebase if the user suddenly closed the app during the runtime

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an e-commerce app using flutter and I've bumped into this when I'm testing my app, it happens on my checkout screen, and received a call suddenly. During the checkout phase of the app, I am writing the items from the cart to the cloud firestore. And when I checked the Firebase Console, items were not saved on my collection. How can I stop a query from executing when something like closing the app happens on the app?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use firestore "transactions". Is recommended when you do checkouts for example because if something happends when you do a transaction operation this will be canceled inmediately. see the documentation here.[enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For clarification purposes, if I were to wrap my queries with this, is it still possible if I have let's say for example more than 4 operations to execute during the runtime?